# Apex Callout failing: Bad Request for integrating with Eventbrite

Tags: apex, error, callout

Working on Integrating Salesforce with Eventbrite. Requirement is to have events created in Salesforce which automatically get created on Eventbrite.Reference: https://www.eventbrite.com/developer/v3/

I'm getting an error 400 as Bad request, I checked all the fields and it looks all fine from my side.Do not understand where am I going wrong. Any help would be highly appreciated.

**Apex class**

```
global class EventbriteCallBackController {
 static Callbacktoken__c cfg = new Callbacktoken__c(SetupOwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId());

public void insertsettings() {
    insert cfg;
 }

@future(callout=true)
public static void EventbriteCallBackControllerMethod(Id EventId){
    String clientId = 'Client Id from App'
    String clientSecret = 'ClientSecret from App'

    String paramCode = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('code');
    system.debug('paramCode '+paramCode);

    Http h = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint('https://www.eventbrite.com/oauth/token');
    System.debug('Event Id is @@@'+ EventId);
    String body = 'code='+paramCode+'&client_secret='+clientSecret+'&client_id='+clientId+'&grant_type=authorization_code';
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setBody(body);
    req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    System.debug('Request is' +req);
    HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
    System.debug('response is' +res.getBody());

    Http h1 = new Http();
    HttpResponse res2 = h1.send(req);
    String resp = res2.getBody();
    System.debug('FINAL RESP IS:'+EncodingUtil.urlDecode(resp, 'UTF-8'));

    Map<string,object > results =(Map<string,object>)Json.deserializeuntyped(resp);
    cfg.access_token__c = (string)results.get('access_token');

    System.debug('Results are ******' +results);

}

public static void createEvent(String id) {

    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint('https://www.eventbrite.com/oauth/token');
    req.setMethod('POST');

    Event eventobj = [select WhoId,StartDateTime,EndDateTime from event where Id=:id];
       Map<String,Object> mapEmp = new Map<String,Object>();
            mapEmp.put('event.name.html',eventobj.WhoId);
            mapEmp.put('event.start.utc',eventobj.StartDateTime);
            mapEmp.put('event.start.timezone','IST');
            mapEmp.put('event.end.utc',eventobj.EndDateTime);
            mapEmp.put('event.end.timezone','IST');
            mapEmp.put('event.currency','INR');                

            String JSONString = JSON.serialize(mapEmp);    
            req.setBody(JSONString);

            System.debug('JSONString is %%%%%%' +JSONString);

            Http http = new Http();
            HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
            System.debug(res.getBody());
      }
  }
```

**Apex Trigger**

```
trigger EventbriteCallBackTrigger on Event (after insert) {

for (Event ld : Trigger.new) {
   EventbriteCallBackController.EventbriteCallBackControllerMethod(ld.Id);
   System.debug('ld.Id');
   }
}
```

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page controller="EventbriteCallBackController" >
   <apex:form >
     <apex:commandButton action="{!insertsettings}" value="insert"/>
 </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Are you able to login? And is this actual code as in the first method you are trying to get response without posting? Please let us know at which line you are getting the issue?

Comment: I'm able to login successfully meaning the app is authorised success.I'm getting the authorization code as well . Getting response without posting meaning ?

Comment: In the method EventbriteCallBackControllerMethod(Id EventId), for the first Http h = new Http(); , you did NOT invoke send() and on the 2nd Http h1 = new Http();, you did NOT set any headers before invoking send(). You must set all the headers & etc.,. on a HTTPRequest and then invoke send() on the HTTPRequest to work as expected.